# MySQL check if dates in db include the dates of given date range

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. Can anyone help me with this.

I got two dates say `From_Date = '2012-04-01'`, `To_Date = '2012-04-17'`. I want to get all the details from the table that contains the date within the given date.

```
Name      Subject  Start_Date  End_Date
Madhu     Science  2011-05-01  2012-05-01
Madhu     Biology  2012-04-01  2012-04-07
Mahesh    Science  2011-05-01  2012-05-01
Jagadesh  Biology  2011-05-01  2012-03-01
```

My answer should contain:

```
Madhu   Science
Madhu   Biology
Mahesh  Science
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table_name 
         where start_date >= "2012-04-01" 
               and end_date <= "2012-04-17"
```

Comment: suppose if i hava a data say Madhu Maths '2012-03-03' '2012-04-5' I want to get this data also in my output

Comment: @jones: Could you explain all the criteria to retrieve result in question itself sorry i did not understand what are you talking about now?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use BETWEEN statement part.

See [mySQL Reference # Between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)